# On referencing environment and scope

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages

If the scope is the "place" where a variable is visible and 
the referencing environment is the set of variables visible in a point
in a program is there a difference between them?

For example [here](http://phobos.ramapo.edu/~amruth/grants/problets/courseware/scope/home.html) is said that """
The converse of scope is referencing environment..."""
but I don't understand very well that assertion!

Answer (score 0):

i'd consider the term 'converse' a misnomer, let alone for contrasting two materially different categories, namely (sets of) variables and locations in code where access to said variable(s) is possible. 'complement' might be a better choice.

for the reason given, yes, there is a difference.

what the reference you're citing probaly intends to extol is variable/parameter masking. consider some variable 'a' declared local to a procedure. assume that part of the procedure body is a block local to which another variable also named 'a' is declared.

the first variable 'a' would be part of the procedure's (local) referencing environment.
its scope extends across the whole procedure body, apart from the block with its own declaration of variable 'a'. in pseudocode (real-world code could be e.g. c, perl, plsql):

```
proc xy
   local a;
   ...
   block
      local a;
      ...
   endblock
   ...
endproc
```

this example is for illustrative purposes only, as details have been left out: it assumes static scoping, abstracts away from other local blocks that might also define some 'a' as well as special mechanisms to access the 'outer a' (namely perl allows runtime access to the whole symbol table).